# ASP.Net MVC Viewmodel Set Property value based on other property

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'v been reading alot of questions how to create your own ASP.NET MVC DefaultModelBinder, which is what I think I need.

So in short what I need is to extract some information from model property and add it to other property on the same model. I thought it would be nice to have an attribute on the property to tell that this is the property to extract from and then specifying the name of the other property where to put it like so:

```
Public Class MyModel
    <MyAttribute(ExtraInfoProperty:="ExtraInfo")>
    Public Property MyProperty As String

    Public Property ExtraInfo As String
End Class
```

And then I would create my own DefaultModelBinder like so

```
Public Class MyModelBinder
    Inherits DefaultModelBinder

       Protected Overrides Sub SetProperty(controllerContext As System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, bindingContext As System.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingContext, propertyDescriptor As System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor, value As Object)
        For Each attribute As Attribute In propertyDescriptor.Attributes
            If TypeOf attribute Is MyAttribute Then
                Dim extraInfo As String = ExtractExtraInfo(value)
                ' Set to ExtraInfo-property
            End If
        Next

        MyBase.SetProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, value)
    End Sub
End Class
```

But is the SetProperty right way to go or do I need to override BindProperty or something else? How would you do this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you give an example of where this property would be used? I get the feeling there might be an easier way using purely the model.

Comment: I might need it in couple of scenarios, for example I would need to extract countrycode from phonenumber and put it to different field ie. +358401234567 -> +358 and 0401234567.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the overhead of custom binding/attributes is needed here. If the purpose of `ExtraInfo` here is to simply extra specific information from another property why not just keep that information in the model itself e.g.

```
Public Class MyModel

    Public Property MyProperty As String

    Public Property ExtraInfo As String
        Get
            Return MyProperty.Substring(0, 4);
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: You might be right that something like this would be enough. But what if you wanted to do a form, where is a field for countrycode and phonenumber. The user can enter both or if he/she doesn't and the countrycode is embedded to the phonenumber, I want to extract it to the second field?